# Manipulando Json com PHP

Tags: php, json, webhook

Boa noite pessoal! To tentando manipular um json vindo de um webhook com php, mas esta complicado.

O site esta me enviando.

```
{
  "affiliate": false,
  "hottok": "XbM56yUGqg5kcdcI7kseXwMsCilSFl3221243",
  "productName": "Produto test postback2 com ç e á",
  "productId": "123456",
  "buyerVO": {
    "phone": "999999999",
    "name": "Postback2 teste",
    "email": "teste@hotmart.com.br"
  },
  "buyer_ip": "127.0.0.1",
  "checkoutCountry": {
    "name": "Brasil",
    "iso": "BR"
  },
  "offer": {
    "code": "n82b9jqz"
  }
}
```

Estou recebendo pelo PHP

```
$dados = file_get_contents("php://input");
var_dump(json_decode($dados));
```

```
object(stdClass)#4(8){
    [\"offer\"]=>object(stdClass)#3(1){
        [\"code\"]=>string(8)\"n82b9jqz\"
        }
        [\"productId\"]=>string(6)\"123456\"
        [\"checkoutCountry\"]=>object(stdClass)#5(2){
            [\"iso\"]=>string(2)\"BR\"
            [\"name\"]=>string(6)\"Brasil\"
        }
        [\"buyer_ip\"]=>string(9)\"127.0.0.1\"
        [\"hottok\"]=>string(37)\"XbM56yUGqg5kcdcI7kseXwMsCilSFl3221243\"
        [\"affiliate\"]=>bool(false)
        [\"productName\"]=>string(34)\"Produtotestpostback2comÃ§eÃ¡\"
        [\"buyerVO\"]=>object(stdClass)#6(3){
            [\"phone\"]=>string(9)\"999999999\"
            [\"name\"]=>string(15)\"Postback2teste\"
            [\"email\"]=>string(20)\"teste@hotmart.com.br\"
        }
}
```

Ele fica assim e eu não consegui achar uma maneira de capturar só o NAME, EMAIL e PHONE.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Para acessar o valor de `name`, `email` e `phone` dentro do objeto `buyerVO`, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```php
$dados = file_get_contents("php://input");
$dadosJson = json_decode($dados);
    
$phone = $dadosJson->buyerVO->phone;
$name = $dadosJson->buyerVO->name;
$email = $dadosJson->buyerVO->email;
    
echo $phone; // imprime "999999999"
echo $name; // imprime "Postback2 teste"
echo $email; // imprime "teste@hotmart.com.br"
```

No código acima, `$dadosJson` recebe o objeto JSON decodificado retornado pelo `json_decode`. Em seguida, cada uma das variáveis `$phone`, `$name` e `$email` recebe o valor correspondente dentro do objeto `buyerVO`, utilizando a sintaxe `$objeto->propriedade`.

Comment: Tem mais um nível, $dadosJson->offer->buyerVO->...

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado